# Trying to call a shell command with Python, gets nothing

Tags: python, django, casperjs

I'm trying to run some integration tests on my web app, using casperjs. To do so, I have the following test class :

```
from django.conf import settings
import unittest
import subprocess

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        print "begin"
        command = "../../n1k0-casperjs-76fc831/bin/casperjs test.js"
        p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, bufsize=0, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        p.wait()
        output = p.stdout.read()
        p.stdout.close()
        print output
        print "end"
```

When I execute this code in a django, or a classif python shell, I get the output of the `js` script. However, when it's called with django, I get this :

```
begin

end
```

Would you guys know why is this happening ?

Comment: As an aside, don't call p.wait() when you've redirected to a pipe. this risks hanging if the pipe fills. Read the pipe to its end, then do the wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible your shell command is actually outputting to stderr?

To redirect stderr to stdout, try this to call the command:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, bufsize=0, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
```